# C# cancellationtokensource set timeout by calling cancelafter, but the real execution time calculated in callback is smaller then the set timeout

Tags: .net, .net-core

When i use an CancellationTokenSource to do something, I set the timeout 20 seconds, and I calculate the execution time in the cts.Token.Register delegate, sometimes the calculate result is small then 20, like 19.999474, the code is like:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    cts.Token.Register(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds);
    });
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            // Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
        }
    }, cts.Token);
}

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
Console.Read();
```

this is a random problem,I can not recurrence on windows, but when I run the code on ubuntu, it is easy to recurrence, the output is:

```
/console# dotnet ConsoleApp.dll
Hello, World!
20.021207
19.999749
19.9997085
19.9997404
19.999752
19.9997758
19.9997996
19.9997977
19.9998211
19.9998472
19.9998671
19.9998864
19.9998947
19.9999292
19.9999329
19.9999648
19.9999677
19.9999977
20.0000164
20.0000181
20.0000277
20.0000516
20.000061
20.0000809
20.0000981
20.0001067
20.0001245
20.0001325
20.0001491
20.0001687
20.0001742
20.0002016
20.0002144
20.0002268
20.0002395
20.0002431
20.000255
20.0002676
20.0002798
20.0002927
20.0003047
20.0003115
20.000323
20.0003712
20.000448
20.0004556
20.0005312
20.0005728
20.0006122
20.000611
```

dotnet info:

```
/console# dotnet --info

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.15
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5edef4b20b

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Comment: Time between executing `var startTime = DateTime.Now;` and `cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));` is clearly non-zero. If you put the first immediately after the second you should get correct results. And `await Task.Delay(1000, cte.Token);` might be wise also.

Comment: thanks, @Charlieface, the timeout delay countdown starts during call cts.CancelAfter, the countdown time add the non-zero time between `var startTime = DateTime.Now;` and `cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));` the total time should always greater then the countdown time 20 seconds, but the result is opposite